# RSpec incorrectly adds id parameter in index routing test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have a `/bar/foos` path that routes to `FoosController`. GETting `/bar/foos` routes to `FoosController#index`, which works as expected when testing manually.

I inherited some routing tests for this which worked fine with Rails 4.2, but started breaking when updating to Rails 5.0.

For some reason RSpec is creating a `id: :foos` parameter in `expect(get: '/bar/foos')` in this spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FoosController do
  describe 'routing' do
    it 'get /bar/foos' do
      expect(get: '/bar/foos').to route_to('foos#index')
    end
  end
end
```

Which yields this error:

```
The recognized options <{"controller"=>"foos", "action"=>"index", "id"=>"foos"}> 
did not match <{"controller"=>"foos", "action"=>"index"}>, difference:.
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-{"controller"=>"foos", "action"=>"index"}
+{"controller"=>"foos", "action"=>"index", "id"=>"foos"}
```

I am using Rails 5.0.2 and rspec 3.6.0.beta2.

Comment: Can you perhaps add your routing (relevant section) as well?